# The name 'ARSubsystemManager' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm working on an AR project to keep track of AR things using Unity, AR Foundation and AR Core.

One of the tasks i need to do is the following:

> Write code to implement the 'systemStateChanged' callback from the
>   ARSubsystemManager class.

I tried to implement the following way:

```
ARSubsytemManager.systemStateChanged += OnStateChanged;
```

but kept on getting the following error:

> The name 'ARSubsystemManager' does not exist in the current context

How can i do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Already manage to do it.

As we can read in [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@2.2/manual/migration-guide.html#arsubsystemmanager-removed),

> The ARSubsystemManager has been removed in 2.0.

Instead, I've used `ARSession.stateChanged += OnStateChanged;`